# Enabled attribute is not declared in nlog rule

Tags: nlog, nlog-configuration

```xml
<logger level="Trace" name="fileLogger" writeTo="FileLogger" enabled="false"/>
```

I would like to disable trace level but I am not able to add enabled property to my rule. Getting warning like enabled attribute is not declared.

Anything else should I do to declare it?

Comment: The fix is now live :)

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

This attribute is indeed missing in the XSD schema of NLog (currently 4.7.1).

You could ignore this warning, as this won't influence the logging. So you could use the `enabled` attribute without problems!

The warning will be fixed in NLog 4.7.2 (PR [here](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/3962))

**Update** NLog 4.7.2 has been released, also https://nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd has been updated

[image]